# Ubuntu deleted my whole filesystem

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, data-recovery

I had Windows running on my single 1TB hard drive.
The disk was divided like this:

- 200GB [OS] partition C:
- 500GB [Data] partition D:
- 60GB - Fedora Instalation

Then, I booted Ubuntu on LiveCD and chose to install it. On the setup screen, it said "Replace Fedora and install Ubuntu over it", which was exactly what I was trying to accomplish.
When setup ended and PC restarted, grub didn't show up. So I rebooted on liveUSB and saw a single 980GB ext4 partition with 4GB used, so I can't access any of my files.

I tried testdisk with no success... I had a lot of important data on that partitions that I can't afford to lose.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: You can try  https://askubuntu.com/questions/463724/recover-windows-after-reinstalling-ubuntu

Comment: Sounds an awful lot like bug #1265192 , https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1265192 ,  but that claims the fix has been released.  What release Ubuntu are you installing?

Comment: "I had a lot of important data on that partitions that I can't afford to lose."  why is that a problem? Just restore your backup. @ubfan1 impossible. 2013, and fixed.

Comment: @ubfan1 It's the 14.04.1 LTS

Comment: @ubfan1 Unfortunately, the fix was for 14.04.2 (thanks murphy)

Comment: Tough luck. If you have no backup, PhotoRec is a last resort. But I suggest that you play safe, clone the drive and do the recovery work on the cloned copy. See this link, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986 -- Scroll down to 'Advanced repair of a partition table, file system and/or recovery of files' -- There are also Windows recovery tools, that might be more user friendly.

Comment: testdisk can find my [Data] partition, but what I'm most worried about was on the [OS] partition, which I had no backup for. Looks like when Ubuntu was installed, it overwrote the entire MFT for the [OS] partition, so probably I have no luck here.

Comment: @Panther In that case, the guy was still able to access his windows files from Ubuntu, which I cannot.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto is it OK if it finds 48000+ partions?

Comment: Well, in case of extreme disk fragmentation it is possible. You might reduce them a bit if you recover the partition table with Testdisk and the run RecuperaBit only on the OS partition.

Comment: testdisk couldn't find my OS partition =(