# Lost Windows after Installing Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I desperately need your help with this:

1) Before this mess started, I was running two HDs (500gb<--Windows 7 on here, and 1tb<--- storage).

2) After repartitioning my 500gb to 398 gb to install ubuntu on the difference (~100gb drive, which I formatted to G::)  I went ahead and tried to install ubuntu.

3) After getting an error during installation, the computer restarted and now windows won't load, or well, it will, as in it can get to the recovery options, but from there it doesn't find any windows, so it is of no help. I tried using my recovery CD, and it loads, but doesn't recognize any OS on the PC so it doesn't let me execute recovery.

4) Now I got really scared, and thought I lost my 500Gb (now 398gb) drive. However, I booted into the ubuntu live USB trial, and saw my 398 gb drive and my 1tb drive there with all of their files inside. I tried running boot repair on ubuntu and it did not help.

5) When I go into windows repair and try to select "load drivers" I see that I can search through my 1tb drive, but my 500gb drive does not show up. Why is that? Why is it recognizing my 1tb drive but not the 500gb drive where windows was installed on? Even when I try to install windows 7 from the repair CD on any drives, only the 1tb drive shows up, so it looks like when I was installing ubuntu on the 500 gb (398/102gb) drive, somehow the drive got reformatted to where its not being detected maybe? My BIOS shows both drives, fortunately.

What can I do? What happened to my windows 7? Is there any way to fix this? I have the following data from the boot repair software on ubuntu:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zcpVqptwkx/

From GParted (with the 500gb drive selected):
https://ibb.co/fQemsp

Also, nothing ever installed on the ~100gb partition I created specifically for ubuntu. Please help!

Ps. when I run my 500 gb(398gb) drive, it starts loading windows for a second and then it BSOD on me. I've had this problem before with the GRUB loader that I fixed by running the windows repair CD, but this is different as I did not even download GRUB or any ubuntu files it seems.

Solutions I've tried so far: [Recover Windows after reinstalling Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463724/recover-windows-)...

(i.e. the Boot into the Windows installation media you borrowed or created. Choose the recovery "Advanced Options" until it offers you a command prompt or shell. I'm not sure if you want "bootrec /fixmbr" or "bootrec /fixboot)

Comment: After you repartitioned the 500Gb and before trying to install Ubuntu, did you reboot and verified that Windows was still working?

Comment: Good question. I can't remember with absolute certainty either way, but I don't think that I did.

Comment: After you make a backup, try installing Ubuntu again from a reliable USB to sda5. Install GRUB when it asks and you will probably be OK. Your issue seem to be due to the installation process fail.

Comment: Thank you Katu, I'll try. Why is it that installing ubuntu is so difficult in the first place. Is there a good website out there with step-by-step instructions? I don't quite get this whole "/" and then "root" etc. Why can't I just choose my partition and have ubuntu take care of the rest.

Comment: Also, the screenshot of GParted I posted, just for clarification, is not correctly showing the status of my 500(398gb) drive. It was more than 70% used, meaning that out of the 500, 320 gb or so was used up. The remainder (180gb) I split into two and one of the halves if where I wanted ubuntu to end up on.

Comment: First time is always tricky but it gets easier. Think that installing Windows in a pc with Ubuntu it would also be complex (probably more). There is tones of help and you are in the right place to find it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu by the way, you can choose your partition and have Ubuntu take care of the rest. Just make sure you format it ext4 and mount it '/'. You will get used to the terminology in no time. Good luck!

Comment: When I tried doing as you suggested, I get the following error "The ext4 file system creation in partition #5 of SCSI5 (0,0,0) (sda) failed."

Comment: There is always a learning curve. This community will help along the way but it doesn't work with the same rules as other forums. Comments section is not for discussion or further questions. Look for tutorials and if your question is unique make sure you put plenty of details so someone can help you better. You might find this link useful https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask