# Can not instsl Ubunt-Server near to Windows 8.1

Tags: system-installation, wubi

I've tried a lot. I was trying to install it using a flash card (two different cards), then with CD's (two) and DVD (one), but my computer just load windows (i've tuned BIOS, like it had to be). I've tried Wubi, but there was an exeption "Could not retrieve the required installation files" (Kubuntu), and "undefined error with disk D" (with Ubuntu). I think that the problem is in my OS - it is 32-bit, when my processor is 64-bit, can it be so? I just don't know what to do, plese, help me.

Comment: When using W8 you have to use the dual boot method where W8 does NOT use hibernation (fast boot). See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting for more info on that. Your system will boot straight into W8 if those settings are not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Read the below two links:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

You need to install the 64 bit version of Ubuntu in UEFI mode.