# If I boot Ubuntu, restart and then Boot Windows, it will give an error in the boot loader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, windows-8

I have Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.10 in my laptop. If I boot into Ubuntu and then reboot and try to boot into Windows 8, in the Windows 8 boot screen (With a light blue background) I will get an error saying "contain errors". Then I have to press `ctrl+alt+del` to reboot and then again if I try Windows it will work. What is happening in here?

Answer (score 6):

The answer to your problem is to disable Fast Boot on Windows 8.

To disable it -

`All Control Panel items` -> `Power Options` -> `System Settings`

Click on the 'Change settings that are currently unavailable' link to make the Shutdown options available and **Untick** the Turn on fast startup option.

The reason for this is explained below with content from this [source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting/452080#452080).

Fast boot explained with an [image](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html):

[image: Windows 8 Fast Startup vs Cold Boot]

During fast boot the system loads the hiberfile and does not use the files on the filesystem.

So the biggest problem, and the worst problem you can have on a computer, is **data loss**: if you create a shared NTFS data partition the hibernation may maintain the file structure so if you try to save a file from Linux into the NTFS partition it will get lost on Windows reboot as it only remembers the old file structure. [See this Ubuntu Forums thread for more information](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1953674).

In general: if a disc is mounted when using fast boot, Windows puts this disc and its content in a hiberfile. Any changes made to the system are gone when the hiberfile is restored. This includes mounted external discs. Ubuntu will refuse to mount a disc that has a hiberfile.

One of the bad messages you see in these topics is getting a "disc has errors" when booting Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 discourages to dualboot ubuntu and winodws both together.
So you should have faced a lot of problems with UEFI, Legcay and BIOS modes and settings.
So the problem you have now is usually seen with most people who use Ubuntu with Windows 8 or later versions..
So I prefer you to use Ubuntu as the main and the only operating system in your computer.
Or If you can't still leave Windows, Then Try removing Ubuntu and install Ubuntu in some another device !
You better do that I think !
Otherwise Windows 8 will always make disturb you with this error !

Answer (score 0):

Try using EasyBCD on your Windows System to reconfigure Windows 8 to use the classic bootloader that was used in Windows 7.That way it will no more interfere with GRUB or other bootloaders making no problem with your system.