# How to resize Linux partiton to other end of partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

This must be a common question but I don't know how to phrase it to find the answer.

**Background:** I have recently got a new laptop, it came with win8, and immediately after removing a ton of bloatware I installed Linux. For some reason I simply split the HD into two main partitions, one for each system. Of course, now that I'm moving data, almost all onto the Linux half system (which I use most) I'm finding that I can't get at it from Windows (which I need for some programmes).

**What I want to do:**  resize both the Windows and Linux paritions and use the space to make a separate data partition.

**Problem:** In gParted I can resize the windows partition (leaving it on the lefthandside) but not the Linux parition. Presumable because I'm using it at the time. How do I do this? And how can I do this so that it ends up on the righthandside, leaving a nice big free space in the middle for my data? (I would post a screenshot but I don't have enough reputation)

**Bonus question:** I was going to make the data partition NTFS. If this seems like a very stupid idea, for whatever reason, please tell now me before I make bad into worse.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, You could use a live CD / USB. It does include gparted

Comment: I agree with @Sneetsher. You should use a live USB/CD to re-size the partitions. IF you want this partition to be accessible from Windows and Ubuntu you can go ahead with the NTFS.

Comment: About the idea, It's good. Actually most who have dual boot use an intermediate data partition. This way, Windows may be left in hibernate mode while switching to Ubuntu.

Comment: You don't want to use hibernation in windows if you dual boot into linux and mount your NTFS partition. You could corrupt them. I don't even talk about [Fast Boot](http://askubuntu.com/q/452071/350004)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Thanks all for the helpful replies. I've not had time to try the live USB yet, and Rob Smith might be right that this is a semi-duplicate, but it doesn't reply to my question about resizing partitions "to the right"?
Explanation: In gparted it lookes like all the data is on the left in the partitions, if I decrease the size of both the windows and Linux partition from the right to the left, the free space won't be adjacent, and instead of one big partition I would have two smaller ones (which is ok, but not ideal).