# Using files from several OS

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I have two operating systems (Windows and Ubuntu) on the same HDD on my laptop. I would like to use some of files (videos, music, doc) in both OS. What is the best way to organize this from performance and stability side? I'm thinking about creating separate NTFS partition for storing data since windows can't read linux partition and I can have problem to mount whole windows OS NTFS partition while Windows is not completely shut downed.

Answer (score 1):

In general your setup will be like this:

- Windows. C: formatted as NTFS as your primairy disk for the OS. Fast boot needs to be disabled or you can loose data on your NTFS disk when you change it from outside Windows since it will boot from a hibernation file that does not have the alterations. Regarding fast boot: [Why disable Fast Boot on Windows 8 when having dual booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting/452080#452080)
- Windows. D: formatted as NTFS
- Ubuntu. Formatted as ext4.

Ubuntu will mount D: automatically. It will set it up as a root owned disk so to access it you need sudo permissions. If this is a dedicated disk for a single user you can change the ownership of that disk (or partition in Ubuntu) using the `chown` command (`chown $USER:$USER /media/{partition}`).

Comment: What is wrong  I store  all files in C: disc I will not have D: ?

Comment: You can do it with just a C: partition. Question: what will you do when you need to re-install Windows and have all your data on C:? Back it up? Got a dvd drive big enough to hold it all?