# Can I reenable Secure boot after having installed Ubuntu 15.04 successfully next to Win 8.1?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8, 15.04, secure-boot

The title is basically my question: I have (seemingly) managed to successfully install 15.04 next to the existing Win 8.1. I did this with Secure boot disabled to be on the safe side.

can I now reenable secure boot? What exactly is it? From what I understand from googling around, it is a feature to only allow 'trusted' OS boot? Is there then someway to add my Ubuntu as 'trusted'? Is it already considered 'trusted' now, and I can reenable secure boot? Or should I just leave it turned off.

Also while googling I read smth about 'fast boot' which one is supposed to turn off (at least in recent versions) Shold I doo this too?

Thanks a lot guys, sorry for being a beginner and probably asking noob questions. I am ready to learn!

:)

Comment: Secure boot is currently Marketing by Windows since they have had so many issues with secuity. But Secure boot only solves boot virus issues and the only large boot virus issue was created & distributed by Sony as DRM. Currently not really required, but in future you may want it. Then just upgrade Ubuntu to signed kernels & grub. Linus on secure boot:  http://www.zdnet.com/torvalds-clarifies-linuxs-windows-8-secure-boot-position-7000011918/

Answer (score 3):

> can I now reenable secure boot?

Sure.  From the 1st link below:

> It is not required to disable SecureBoot in the firmware to install Ubuntu on a Windows 8 machine. Ubuntu 12.04.2+ are SecureBoot-compatible. Any machine that ships with the recommended Microsoft Third-Party Marketplace keys in firmware will be able to boot Ubuntu under SecureBoot. If there is any problem file a launchpad bug for the shim package.

---

> Also while googling I read smth about 'fast boot' which one is supposed to turn off (at least in recent versions) Should I do this too?

Yes.

> What exactly is secure boot/fast boot?

Topics on secure boot and fast boot:

- [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)
- [Why disable Fast Boot on Windows 8 when having dual booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting)

The 1st link is an in-depth how-to. The 2nd one is mine and has an image explaining fast boot.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot Rinzwind! I read through both (as well as I could) and it is very insightful. I have just tried to reenable secure boot and it was then not possible to boot. Am I right in suspecting that it would only work if I would have left Secure Boot on when installing Ubuntu? Thus it is not possible to reenable it after one has installed Linux / dualboot in 'insecure boot' mode? Or if it is possible, how would one go about doing it? Thanks again for your help, it is very appreciated. :)