# unable to mount ntfs partition created inside widows 10

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

If i try to open any of partition, I get error message in a box.

```
Error mounting /dev/sda8 at /media/viratraaz/Documents: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda8" "/media/viratraaz/Documents"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda8': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to disable Windows fast start-up option.

Open Control Panel -> **Energy Settings**  and select **Change what the power buttons do**.

Choose **Change settings that are currently unavailable**, scroll down and uncheck
**Turn on fast start-up (recommended)**.

Restart the computer and you won't have this error anymore.

---

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting) for more informations about Windows Fast Boot.

Answer (score 13):

It happens because of the partial hibernation of Windows (From Windows 8). I hope you are trying to open a drive from your dual booted system which is shutdowned from Windows last time.

A quick and dirty way to fix this problem is, executing the following command on each drives:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdxx
```

where xx is device and partition letter and number ie: /dev/sda1

For more details: [WORKAROUNDS FOR NOT BEING ABLE TO MOUNT THE WINDOWS 8 PARTITION IN LINUX DUE TO HIBERNATION](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/06/workarounds-for-not-being-able-to-mount.html)

Comment: Can't imagine why this is a dirty way because it's using the special utility even named ntfsfix.

Comment: The reason for dirty is here:
According to the manual, ntfsfix - fix common errors and force Windows to check NTFS". However, this problem occurs not because of errors but because of hibernation.
For more details: http://disq.us/p/yajyhr