# Is dual-boot Windows 10 with hibernation and Ubunutu 18.04 dangerous?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 18.04, windows-10, hibernate

I want 3 partitions on the SSD of my Thinkpad (additional to the small standard partitions for windows recovery and so on):

1.) Windows 10 (This partition is called "C" in Windows)

2.) NTFS data partition used by both OS

3.) Ubuntu 18.04

I read a lot about people not being able to mount other partitions with Ubuntu because they get warning messages, telling them that Windows is in hibernation ([Unable to mount Windows 10 partition; it "is in an unsafe state"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state), [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation?noredirect=1&lq=1), [unable to mount ntfs partition created inside widows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655992/unable-to-mount-ntfs-partition-created-inside-widows-10?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

I am fine with getting warning messages and I found how to shut down Windows with deactivated fast start-up(see https://askubuntu.com/a/655995/865596, https://askubuntu.com/a/843161/865596) or to restart instead of a shutdown to avoid hibernation-like behavior (see https://askubuntu.com/a/843373/865596).

But I am very afraid of corrupted data or even bricking my system.

So can I rely on getting warning messages when the other OS is hibernating? Or is it possible that when I boot Ubuntu while windows is still in hibernation that I can destroy something without getting warned before doing so? And how dangerous is it to boot Windows 10 while Ubuntu 18.04 is hibernating?

Related question: When people are writing about not being able to mount their "windows partition" do they actually mean the partition 1.) Windows 10 partition (I cannot think of any situation where I would like to mount this partition in write mode. By the way: is it possible to forbid Ubuntu to ever mount this partition with writing rights?) or do they mean the 2.) NTFS data partition?

Summarizing my question: Is it safe to use the following configuration:

1.) Windows 10

-with hibernation

-without fast startup (or with fast-start-up and always trying to restart windows before booting Ubuntu like described in https://askubuntu.com/a/843373/865596)

2.) NTFS data partition used by both OS

3.) Ubuntu 18.04

-without hibernation (or would it even be safe to use hibernation in Ubuntu too?)

-Is there any Fast start up option in Ubuntu 18.04 that should be deactivated for a dual boot configuration?

Comment: Fast Boot is an UEFI setting. That skips any UEFI check on system changes and immediately jumps to boot. Often then you do not have time to get into UEFI to make changes. But cold boot usually works. And both Windows & Ubuntu have ways to get into UEFI if they are working. Fast start up in Windows is hibernation, & it is set on all NTFS partitions and Windows turns it back on with updates. YOu can usually mount read only, but default mount will not work to prevent you from writing a file that then will not be there when hibernation is restored. Ubuntu normally boots quick enough.

Comment: Thank you! I always wanted to talk about "fast start-up"  not about "Fast Boot", so I corrected this in my question. You said "... but default mount will not work to prevent you from writing a file that then will not be there when hibernation is restored". How can I change my settings to get warning when I try to mount a NTFS-data-partition while windows is hibernating. I just want to get those warnings that all other people are complaining about like: "“is in an unsafe state”  or https://askubuntu.com/questions/655992/unable-to-mount-ntfs-partition-created-inside-widows-10?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: If Windows is hibernated or needs chkdsk, then you get from Ubuntu's NTFS driver the error message posted in link. It will not default mount. You can manually mount with read/only parameters but default is read/write.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by manually mounting? When I click the partition in the default graphical interface "Files", it gets mounted. Does this use the NTFS driver? Would i get a warning in this case?

Comment: Yes, that is auto mount and would give some sort of warning and not mount it. Then go into Windows and turn off fast start or make other repairs. Few fixes from Linux work on Windows.  Manual mount is using terminal/command line where you can set the ro (read only) parameter rather than the default rw read/write.