# I am getting mount error while booting UBUNTU 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, mount

[image: mount error boot]

> An error occurred while mounting /mnt/C490822890822152

Here is what I get when i choose to boot Ubuntu 14.04 in grub 2.
I can still boot Ubuntu by pressing <kbd>S</kbd> key, and can access to root terminal by pressing <kbd>M</kbd> key. I installed all recent Ubuntu base update, but it still occurs.

What is `/mnt/C49082289022152` and how do I solve this error?

Comment: Yes i am, I installed UBUNTU after Windows 10 and using grub2 as boot loader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that `/mnt/C49082289022152` is the partition where your Windows 10 is installed.

When Ubuntu boots, it tries to automatically mount this partition but it does not work because Windows fast startup is enabled.

Disable it :

Boot into Windows, open Control Panel, type "change what power buttons do" and select "**Change what the power buttons do**".

Select "**Change settings that are currently unavailable**", scroll down and uncheck "**Turn on fast start-up (recommended)**".

Restart your computer ...

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting) for more informations about Windows Fast Boot.

---

If this does not work, disable all Windows partitions to auto-mount at Ubuntu Startup to bypass this error:

1. Open `Disks`
2. Select your Windows partition
3. Click **Options** > **Edit Mount Options**
4. Uncheck **Mount at startup**

Comment: Yes, you are right with that Windows 10 partition. But I checked the `fast start-up` option, it was already unchecked. So instead i went to UBUNTU Disk Utility, and unchecked `mount at startup` option for all windows partition and now the error does not occur. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had put my Windows account on hibernate and then upon restarting the system, i got an exact same error for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I just went back to windows and shut it down and came back to linux and it signed it easily. I did try it 2 more times the error was repeatable so i now know that when Windows had been mounted in the boot, Linux can't enter the boot sequence.

Comment: Your answer does not seem to answer the OPs question. They do not say they have a dual-boot config. Be specific to answer the question.

Comment: I hope you can read carefully again and make a simple assessment from the posts above. I don't know what makes you think that @nerisona didn't have dual boot when they are clearly talking about it from the begining itself. Be polite in your comment.