# drives mount after switch to windows and get back to ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, automount

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 beside Windows 8
When I boot Ubuntu windows NTFS drives don't open and show this:

> Error mounting /dev/sda5/ at /media/username/Ali : command-line mount
>   -t "ntfs" -o

[image]

But after restarting and booting windows and then get back to ubuntu I can access drives.
What to do drives mount without booting windows?

Comment: Please post a link of your screenshot. I will add it for you.

Comment: http://i62.tinypic.com/2rgz0hf.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the instructions already given by @hg8, you should and have to **disable hibernation**.

To accomplish this, boot Windows and open **command prompt as administrator** and execute :

```
powercfg /h off
```

Shutdown the machine (not reboot) completely. Then start your computer and boot into ubuntu.

So with Fast Boot turned off and hibernation disabled you will be able to mount NTFS partitions.

Comment: Today it happened again   same error

Answer (score 1):

Your problem probably is the Windows fast startup option. You have to disable it.

Boot Windows, open Control Panel, type "change what power buttons do" and select the link "**Change what the power buttons do**".

Select the link "**Change settings that are currently unavailable**", scroll down and uncheck "**Turn on fast start-up (recommended)**".

Restart the computer and you won't have this error anymore.

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting) for more informations about Windows Fast Boot.

Comment: I did it but again same error

Comment: Do you  properly shutdown Windows before booting Ubuntu ? (no suspend, no hibernation etc...) ?

Comment: Yes I completely turned off computer and unplugged it then directly boot to ubuntu