# Unable to load/mount Window 8 hard disk partition

Tags: 14.04, windows, mount, ntfs, hibernate

After installing Ubuntu 14.04 along with window 8 I am unable to load Windows and unable to mount hard disk partition.

The message shown is given below :

```
Error mounting /dev/sda6 at /media/jeetu/24386BED386BBD04: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda6" "/media/jeetu/24386BED386BBD04"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda6': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the Windows 8 fast startup option - you have to disable it.

In Windows open Control Panel, type "*change what power buttons do*" and select

**Change what the power buttons do** > **Change settings that are currently unavailable**

Scroll down and uncheck **Turn on fast start-up (recommended)**.

Restart your computer and you won't have this error anymore.

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting) for more information about Windows Fast Boot.

Comment: I'm not able to load window any more, after installing ubuntu, as  I already mention