# Try to edit grub | How to make entry boot to Windows 10 rightly?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I'm trying to add Windows entry to GRUB2 on my Ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS.

Although "Windows 10" selection is there, but it fails to boot and warns

`EFI invalid ...`

Below are a few screenshots I've captured:

[image: Screetshot from Gparted]

[image: Screenshot form Grub-customized]

Please tell me how to use grub-customiser to make the entry boot rightly to Windows 10.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you say you see the following message when you try to boot Windows:

```
EFI invalid ...
```

Is that *exactly* what you see, or are you omitting something and replacing it with the elipsis (`...`)? If the latter, please report the *complete* error message you see, since it may contain important information. Also, are you getting this message when you launch your customized entry or another one that was created automatically?

Second, it's possible that you're running into [this bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1091464) If so, the easiest workaround is to disable Secure Boot on your computer. Other alternatives include using another distribution's GRUB (OpenSUSE's is said to work) or using my [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) instead of GRUB.

Third, your GRUB Customizer screen shot shows what looks like an entry for launching Windows in BIOS mode; but your GParted screen shot indicates a GPT disk, which in turn means that Windows must be booting in EFI mode. Thus, your BIOS-mode entry simply will not work. The GRUB configuration scripts *should* detect the EFI-mode Windows boot loader, so there should be no need to create a custom entry. Typing `sudo update-grub` should re-run the setup script. That might pick up your Windows boot loader.

Finally, if GRUB's setup scripts are *not* detecting Windows, it could be that your [EFI System Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) (ESP; your `/dev/sda2`, which should be mounted at `/boot/efi` in Ubuntu) is damaged. This often happens because of a failure to [disable Fast Startup in Windows.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting) See [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) for information on how to do this. Note that you may also need to disable hibernation, as described [here.](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html)