# Ubuntu installed, but GRUB not showing up

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my Lenovo Thinkpad laptop. I was trying to have dual boot by installing Windows 10 along with the existing Ubuntu. Since I had to reinstall GRUB2, I downloaded boot-repair which finished the reinstallation with an error.

http://paste2.org/Nps1AXGF

Now system is not booting at all. It is getting stuck at boot menu. GRUB is not showing up.

I tried reinstalling Ubuntu and Windows. Now there is only Ubuntu in the system. Same issue. The system is not booting to Ubuntu.

Comment: Please try this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/787778/497359 , Including the **NOTE** section. (Multi boot key in HP systems is `f9` ,  Dell -  `f12` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already heard from boot-repair-disk:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/

This helped me a lot in the past. Simply generate a live usb stick using boot-repair-disk and boot from the stick. Of course you should have already saved all your files. Who knows what might happen...

Edit: You can generate the live stick by using for example unetbootin.

Comment: boot-repair-disk helped. Somehow the EFI System Partition was corrupted. I used the delete OS option and deleted EFI System Partition. Then, I did a clean installation of Ubuntu and now system is booting properly. Thanks.