# Dual boot not working

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

After installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from USB drive to unallocated space on my hard disk, when I reboot the computer it boots directly into Windows 10 without showing a dual boot option.

I followed the instructions given here: [everydaylinuxuser.com](http://goo.gl/6v0vqs). I had previously set UEFI to legacy BIOS and reinstalled Windows 10 together with Windows 7.

I then decided to install Ubuntu. I have reinstalled Ubuntu several times but I still cannot create a dual boot option on restart.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

[image: You can see my disk partition layout here:]

Comment: Please try this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/787778/497359 , Including the **NOTE** section. (Multi boot key in HP systems is `f9` ,  Dell -  `f12` )