# Installing Ubuntu on windows 10 laptop where I have BIOS and no secure boot, is it Safe?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, bios

I want to install ubuntu and my windows 10 does not have secure boot, I have BIOS, can I install latest LTS without any risk? I want to use both systems and I have windows on C drive. I am planning to have Ubuntu on another drive where there is plenty of space. 
Do I need to take any special care? I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ISO file downloaded. Should I create a USB installation from it, or running it directly is safe?
Thank you!

Comment: You cannot easily run the ISO. You need to create installer. If system is Windows 10 and pre-installed it is UEFI, but if upgrade from Windows 7 then probably BIOS. If installing to second drive/sdb, then only use Something Else install option and install grub2's boot loader to sdb drive. Keep Windows boot loader in sda drive. After install set BIOS to boot sdb and if Windows has issues, you can still directly boot it from BIOS settings. http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: thank you, after going through your link I saw what you mean! It is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some problems with secure boot - but it seems like most of them have fixes

Take a look at
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1091464

Booting from USB (without installing ubuntu) is safe, regardless of Secure Boot. Your system should just normally boot windows after you remove the drive.

Edit:
Without secure boot, its safe to use Ubuntu with windows 10. You will HAVE to disable fast startup (see [windows10 & 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787744/windows-10-and-ubuntu-16-04-lts-dual-boot-problem)).I have installed it on a partition and on different drives in the past (not on a laptop tho) and haven't come across any big issues.

Comment: thank you about the USB drive part of the question, the real decision I need is - can I use D drive of my same hard disk which has windows (on another partition) and still dual boot? I have BIOS so no question of secure boot.

Comment: You need to make sure to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode if Windows is UEFI. And you can share a NTFS partition as long as Windows fast start or always on hibernation is off. All NTFS partitions are hibernated if it is on and then Linux NTFS driver will not see it correctly. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions  & More explanation of NTFS driver & Windows hibernation
http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: @Pushkaraj, The `D:` drive in Windows terminology is a partition (maybe `/dev/sda2`) in linux terminology. You can share it between Windows and Ubuntu as a data partition, if you keep the NTFS file system. But if you want to use it for Ubuntu (to install Ubuntu in that location), you must create another file system or let the Ubuntu installer create another file system. The standard file system in Ubuntu is `ext4`, which is a linux file system.