# Mount a secondary partition to r/w with Fast boot enabled

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 16.04, mount, windows

I have one 1tb drive in my laptop partitioned into 3 partitions:

```
1 - Windows 10
2 - My files
3 - Ubuntu 16.04
```

I want to make the second partition (My files) a shared partition between Windows and Ubuntu, and I can't mount it in ubuntu to r/w I know how to mount it "ro"! Because I have fast boot enabled in Windows. Is there any way I can leave it enabled and make the second partition r/w in both OS?

Comment: Not possible due to how fast boot works in Windows. You have to disable fast boot.

Comment: but the second partition doesn't have Windows in it. I want to make it accessible for both Windows and Ubuntu

Comment: We know what you want but it is impossible with fast boot enabled . See http://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting and http://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there really is no solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to the way Windows handles Fast Boot, there really is no solution other then to disable fast boot.

There is a discussion here - [Why disable Fast Boot on Windows 8 when having dual booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting)

and various windows sites - http://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/

Scroll down on that page a bit

> When you shut down a computer with Fast Startup enabled, **Windows locks
>   down the Windows hard disk. You won’t be able to access it from other
>   operating systems if you have your computer configured to dual-boot.**
>   ***Even worse, if you boot into another OS and then access or change
>   anything on the hard disk (or partition) that the hibernating Windows
>   installation uses, it can cause corruption.*** If you’re dual booting,
>   it’s best not to use Fast Startup or Hibernation at all.

It is irrelevant what partition you are using so it affects all partitions windows uses, both the primary installation partition (C:) and data partitions will be affected.