# Unable to install ubuntu via dual boot through USB

Tags: usb-installation

I am using the following system:
Lenovo Legion Y520-151KBM with windows 10, intel core i7, 16GB RAM, 256 GB SSD + 1 TB HDD, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 Max-Q (6GB).
I am trying to install ubuntu 16.04 on my system via dual boot using a USB stick. I clicked the install ubuntu option in the grub menu and I only got a black screen with the cursor and nothing happened after that. I tried again, this time I tried try ubuntu without installing option and got the same result. After searching a bit through net, I typed e at try ubuntu without installing option and replaced the words 'quiet splash' with 'nomodeset' and got the following output after which the procedure again stopped.[output after trying nomodeset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Ugf.jpg)

Not able to figure out any solution, this time I tried booting ubuntu 14.04 instead of 16.04 and I got the ubuntu home screen. After clicking install ubuntu icon, I reach the following screen which tells me that the windows installation is not detected.[no windows detected while trying 14.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2d5c.jpg)

can someone give me the possible solutions to both the problems? Though I would prefer to have 16.04 on my system.

Comment: Did you disable fast boot? See [Why disable Fast Boot on Windows 8 when having dual booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting).

Comment: @J.Starnes I disabled fast boot and tried booting both 16.04 and 14.04 and again got the same results. nothing changed.