# Is a 9 seconds delay before the splash screen normal on Xubuntu?

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu, uefi, xfce

I seem to get a 9 seconds delay while starting Xubuntu, https://youtu.be/P3I5fh9LxRE. When disabling the `quiet splash` options in the grub configuration, I could see that Grub starts after this delay. I have tried solutions from other StackExchange questions as changing the Grub timeout from 0 to 1. I have also tried disabling secure boot in UEFI.

Here is an output of systemd-analyze:

```
Startup finished in 2.869s (kernel) + 9.095s (userspace) = 11.964s 
graphical.target reached after 9.087s in userspace
```

I'm not sure if it is normal to get such a delay as this has never happened on Windows 10. My Xubuntu installation on another PC also has a similar delay.

Comment: Why are you comparing Xubuntu with Windows 10? Windows doesn't boot every time at all. I don't see any problems.

Comment: I have similar boot times in my setup. Check `systemd-analyze blame` for more details about your boot times

Comment: As @Pilot6 said, Win10 has quick boot which is more like restoring from hibernation than doing a cold boot everytime. Check this https://askubuntu.com/a/452080/271196