# External Hard Disk failure?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd

First of all sorry if this is a duplicate question but I just want to make sure that I don't erase anything from my Hard disk.

Anyway, my Hard disk is a Seagate Backup Plus Slim and I used it on Windows for a decent amount of time(3~5 months).

I decided to also use it for my Linux system(Ubuntu Studio 20.04LTS).

I then put some Ardour and Blender projects on it and tried to copy some of them into my Laptop running Windows.

When I was copying the files, it said there was an error so I thought I just need to recopy the files so I tried to delete them, an error popped up, so I proceeded to continue the job on Ubuntu but when I re-plugged it on Ubuntu it's not showing anymore and same on Windows.

Thank you and have a great day~!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What error? What does decent amount of time mean?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Studio 20.04LTS, I forgot what error it is on windows tho, I am very sorry about that, and the "decent amount of time" is about 3~5months

I hope this helps <33

Comment: Edit the question and put in the information not as a comment and without the error no one will be able to help.

Comment: I see, my mistake, but regarding about the Windows error, I believe I can't recreate it anymore since as stated above it cannot interact or even show up on my system. Either way, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Checking consistency of the file system**

Before suspecting a hard drive failure, make sure your file system is healthy and consistent. Likely, it currently is not.

This is likely an ntfs formatted partition because you tell you also use it with Windows. To check and repair the file system:

- Connect the drive to MS Windows
- Run the disk checking tools of Windows on the drive. (In principle, the linux tool `ntfs` can repair an ntfs drive to some extent. However, ntfs is a proprietary file format, so only Windows tools know all the ins and outs of the file system. Hence the recommendation to check on Windows.)
- Correctly disconnect the drive, i.e. first using the icon in the tray.

That ensures the file system is now healthy and consistent. Unless there is a hardware issue, you will now be able to use it correctly under linux.

**Keeping file systems on removable drives consistent**

- Always **disconnect** a drive **by software** first, using the tray icon in Windows, and right-clicking the drive in your file manager to remove the drive in Linux. You can also use the `eject` command.
- Alternatively, **fully shut down** the system before disconnecting the drive. With Windows, however, this is safe only if ["Windows Fast Start" is turned off](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1362810/does-ubuntu-work-with-fast-boot-turned-on/1362819?noredirect=1#comment2339449_1362819).

**Potential hardware failure**

If, after these precautions, you still encounter issues with the drive, then you can start suspecting hardware failure.

Comment: Hello there! Thanks for answering, but what disk checking tool should I run in windows, currently I am using `chkdsk`

Comment: For sure a Windows forum can help you for that. I was familiar with Windows up to XP. You can use chkdsk /f (switch necessary to also repair) but there is also a graphical tool.

Comment: Thank you and have great day!